# How do process my research data with python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

For some research I am doing at school, a system I am using outputs data in the form of a list like this:

```py
data = [
   ['Original Scan', 0, 23.146309375681962, 36.534373218200166],
   [5, 0.00015808600180850993, 14.03180693064792, 25.130059826146226],
   ['Degauss 1', 0.0001676565009807885, 18.33996552587951, 29.85652818261233],
   [5, 0.00019503035220289067, 19.595745760249194, 29.495763024929236],
   ['Degauss 1', 0.000210060256315139, 17.858656990945203, 32.31149763207207],
   [5, 0.00019177307042011343, 16.65182665346039, 26.7927902597764],
   ['Degauss 1', 0.00022217761737506128, 15.408535501863321, 26.37129524475812],
   [5, 0.0002954777643168222, 22.794048652120257, 36.9308761639897],
   ['Degauss 1', 0.0003189866582346615, 14.948934127369814, 25.609259161487458],
   [5, 0.0001905522028747761, 19.11779411980358, 26.93926634886425],
   ['Degauss 1', 0.0002596848642076495, 16.52493208221349, 36.08480345294324],
   [5, 0.00022975870192903274, 15.457531404917487, 31.469277860171324],
   ['Degauss 1', 0.0002730733953392396, 13.59039025942238, 29.017694984805246],
   [5, 0.0003324072595179313, 17.418260625360308, 39.9332167049047],
   ['Degauss 1', 0.00032467106202796296, 16.411012017845984, 27.238517089900547],
   [5, 0.00019501569409976008, 16.434946285329566, 36.082764772986465],
   ['Degauss 1', 0.0001999899241164997, 13.621001825807184, 33.85443152374901],
   [5, 0.0002480635909895036, 17.14186587678462, 31.212129845941686],
   ['Degauss 1', 0.0003010572239328449, 15.488957095845786, 30.596635683607417],
   [5, 0.00024775935778942717, 14.550641342289275, 40.762954460951356],
   ['Degauss 1', 0.00016019323753253822, 13.847293394514374, 28.42756792202193]
]
```

How can I get the third element of each sub-list from this dataset, and then place it in a new list?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried?

Comment: d2 = [x[2] for x in data]  ?

Comment: The title of the question mentions that the values should be removed from the original list, however the body of your question does not mention it. Is that also required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is how it can be done in Python:**

Note, this does not 'remove' the items from list-1.  Do you really want to modify the first dataset?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

data = [['Original Scan', 0, 23.146309375681962, 36.534373218200166], 
    [5, 0.00015808600180850993, 14.03180693064792, 25.130059826146226],
    ['Degauss 1', 0.0001676565009807885, 18.33996552587951, 29.85652818261233],
    [5, 0.00019503035220289067, 19.595745760249194, 29.495763024929236], 
    ['Degauss 1', 0.000210060256315139, 17.858656990945203, 32.31149763207207],
    [5, 0.00019177307042011343, 16.65182665346039, 26.7927902597764],
    ['Degauss 1', 0.00022217761737506128, 15.408535501863321, 26.37129524475812], 
    [5, 0.0002954777643168222, 22.794048652120257, 36.9308761639897],
    ['Degauss 1', 0.0003189866582346615, 14.948934127369814, 25.609259161487458],
    [5, 0.0001905522028747761, 19.11779411980358, 26.93926634886425],
    ['Degauss 1', 0.0002596848642076495, 16.52493208221349, 36.08480345294324],
    [5, 0.00022975870192903274, 15.457531404917487, 31.469277860171324],
    ['Degauss 1', 0.0002730733953392396, 13.59039025942238, 29.017694984805246],
    [5, 0.0003324072595179313, 17.418260625360308, 39.9332167049047], 
    ['Degauss 1', 0.00032467106202796296, 16.411012017845984, 27.238517089900547],
    [5, 0.00019501569409976008, 16.434946285329566, 36.082764772986465],
    ['Degauss 1', 0.0001999899241164997, 13.621001825807184, 33.85443152374901],
    [5, 0.0002480635909895036, 17.14186587678462, 31.212129845941686], 
    ['Degauss 1', 0.0003010572239328449, 15.488957095845786, 30.596635683607417],
    [5, 0.00024775935778942717, 14.550641342289275, 40.762954460951356],
    ['Degauss 1', 0.00016019323753253822, 13.847293394514374, 28.42756792202193]]

List = []

for item in data:
  List.append(item[2])

print(List)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following snip of code I always use in those cases:

```
new_list=[] #list that will contain each third value
index=2 #in your case this is 2 to get the third value
[new_list.append(colm[index]) for colm in data]
print(new_list)
```

Feel free to ask any questions.